# Passing a password from login

Tags: java, string, swing, authentication, passwords

I am using java frames to create a small project.
In the login frame I receive a username and password from the user.
After checking for validity, I must pass this username and password to another frame's constructor (called UserFrame).
I am passing as a string and it seems unsecure.
Is there a good method to achieve passing a password from one frame to another in java?

```
String user=userField.getText();
String pwd= passField.getText();
if (user.equals("username") && pwd.equals("password"))
      Home x= new Home(user,pwd);
```

Comment: are you using swing? you should provide some code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Again, ***never*** use `getText()` with JPasswordFields. The API will tell you so, that it has been deprecated.

Comment: As you know java is strong type language, what type is `passField` or `userField` we can't imagine, for better help sooner always is better to post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and it's probably you find the problem yourself

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  In this case, the log-in should be a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `JPasswordField#getPassword()` returns `char[]`, and so you could handle the password as it is given to you (assuming that you are using a JPasswordField): as an array of char. Either that or hash it somehow and pass the hash code.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Yes I am using a JPasswordField. However I used getText() for simplicity as it returns a String. Does the character array guarentee additional security than a string when being passed from one frame to another?

Don't use `getText()` for the very reason that you're asking your question: you shouldn't handle passwords as Strings at all as this increases the ease of their discovery. Look at the API for the JPasswordField class and you'll see that `getText()` has been deprecated for this very same reason. As a general rule you should not use deprecated methods.

---

**Edit 2** 
You state:

> Ok. Now I understand it. But how can a password be passed from one frame to another? Does passing a char[] guarantee security?

As far as I know, nothing *guarantees* security, but handling the password as a char array does improve security. Use a char[] constructor parameter or a setter method that takes a char[] parameter.

Comment: Yes I am using a JPasswordField. However I used getText() for simplicity as it returns a String.
Does the character array guarentee additional security than a string when being passed from one frame to another?

Comment: Ok. Now I understand it. But how can a password be passed from one frame to another?
Does passing a char[] guarantee security?

Comment: @user2670866: see Edit 2

Answer (score 1):

passField.getText() is deprecated, so I would NOT recommend using that.  Instead, try using passField.getPassword(), like this:

```
String pwd= new String(passField.getPassword());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getPassword() method avaialable. But this method return type is char array.You may want to convert it into String.

```
char a[]= jPasswordField1.getPassword();
 String pswd = new String (a);
```

Or simply,

```
String pswd= new String (jPasswordField1.getPassword());
```

Pass the id,pswd to other frame constructor as

```
new JFrame2(id,pswd);
```

Comment: I used getText() method directly instead.
however my conern is about passing a string from one frame to another?
Does java handle any auto encoding methods? or any object like 'password'?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on something like this. You probably don't want to pass around unencrypted Strings, and writing an encryption class isn't too onerous. Have a look at this page for a guide on encryption: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html

I would encrypt the text on entry and then pass around the resulting byte array.